# Flink JobExecutionException: akka.client.timeout

Tags: java, intellij-idea, akka, apache-flink

I am using `Flink v.1.4.0`.

I am trying to run a job using the `DataSet API` through `IntelliJ`. Note that If I run the same job through the `Flink UI` the job runs fine. In order to run the job, I need to first specify through environment variables the amount of data that will be processed. When the amount is relatively small, the job runs fine. But as it gets bigger I am beginning to get the following error:

```
ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to the console...
31107 [main] ERROR com.company.someLib.SomeClass - Error executing pipeline
org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Couldn't retrieve the JobExecutionResult from the JobManager.
at org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobClient.awaitJobResult(JobClient.java:300)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobClient.submitJobAndWait(JobClient.java:387)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.minicluster.FlinkMiniCluster.submitJobAndWait(FlinkMiniCluster.scala:565)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.minicluster.FlinkMiniCluster.submitJobAndWait(FlinkMiniCluster.scala:539)
at org.apache.flink.client.LocalExecutor.executePlan(LocalExecutor.java:193)
at org.apache.flink.api.java.LocalEnvironment.execute(LocalEnvironment.java:91)
at com.ubs.digital.comms.graph.emailanalyser.EmailAnalyserPipeline.lambda$runPipeline$1(EmailAnalyserPipeline.java:120)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1374)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
at com.ubs.digital.comms.graph.emailanalyser.EmailAnalyserPipeline.runPipeline(EmailAnalyserPipeline.java:87)
at com.ubs.digital.comms.graph.emailanalyser.EmailAnalyserPipeline.main(EmailAnalyserPipeline.java:65)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobClientActorSubmissionTimeoutException: Job submission to the JobManager timed out. You may increase 'akka.client.timeout' in case the JobManager needs more time to configure and confirm the job submission.
```

I can see that the advice is:

```
You may increase 'akka.client.timeout' in case the JobManager needs more time to configure and confirm the job submission.
```

but I suspect that the problem goes deeper than that. But in order to get there I need to first configure `akka.client.timeout`. How do I do this **in IntelliJ**? and how long should the timeout be?

Furthermore, what's really causing this? Do I need to increase my heap memory or something? Thanks.

Comment: Try to upgrade to flink 1.4.1 and check http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/flink-user/201705.mbox/%3CCAGr9p8BXhLJseEXwzvXLk+drotyp1yxjY4N4_qgeRdzxz8UQEA@mail.gmail.com%3E

Comment: Upgrading to 1.4.1 is a bit tricky right now, as many dependencies will need to change. I am looking at how to "... increase akka's network stack (=remoting)", but there is no such field I should increase. Is it `akka.framesize`?

Comment: the change from 1.4.0 to 1.4.2 is much less painless than if you were doing the upgrade from 1.3.2 to 1.4.0. Just in my experience. As far as timeout value, do you have a code sample you can share? I know for the data stream API (if you use the Kafka Connector as a source) you can adjust the timeout in the properties you pass to the FlinkKafkaConsumer. If you give some insight into how you are setting up your source I could advise better.

Comment: Ok. I will have to do that at some point anyway; definitely once a major release is out (1.5.0) but for now I am keeping to 1.4.0. Thanks for the input though. I am sure that with the upgrade much of these issues will be resolved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to figure it out and it was not so difficult either. All I had to do was go to `Run > Edit Configurations` and under the `Configucation` tab in the `Program arguments` field, add the following:

```
-Dakka.client.timeout:600s
-Dakka.ask.timeout:600s
```

I should note, however, that this did not solve the problem I was having altogether.

Comment: Does the settings work while we pass this as program arguments?

Answer (score 0):

You can set this property via the flink configuration file. See https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/ops/config.html#distributed-coordination-via-akka

So in flink-conf.yaml you would add for example:

```
akka.client.timeout: 10min
```

But it seems like the data is being processed in the wrong place. Do you perhaps load the data in a constructor rather than in a `map` or `run` function?

Comment: Thanks for the response but I already knew that. What I am trying to find out is whether this can be done through IntelliJ.